# Nodes are not applied to a few meshes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

I set all materials in brender render. But I changed it to cycles. And changing materials again but only 2 mesh couldn't change. Cannot change even color it stays white. What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert materials from Blender Internal to Cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles) and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27468/is-it-possible-to-transport-materials-between-the-internal-render-and-cycles-ren

Comment: make sure your two materials have everything set up for Cycles, 'Use nodes' option is mandatory for each of them, Also you might have a combination of nodes which are obsolete since you changed from internal to Cycles and might have created those materials before conversion, delete the old 'material' and 'output' and add new ones.