# No materials showing up in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, shaders

So im trying to make a minecraft animation test with my world and i want really good lightning. The only problem is when i render in cycles none of my materials show up like they do in blender render.

[image: Blender render]

[image: Cycles render]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39371/textures-disappear-when-the-rendering-engine-is-switched-to-cycles/39373#39373   http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27468/is-it-possible-to-transport-materials-between-the-internal-render-and-cycles-ren and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles