# Converting Blender Internal Textures to Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, conversion

i have looked around the internet, and even on this site, but the answers seemed to not work with me yet.

I have a Blender Internal texture like this
[image]

And a Cycles Render like this
[image]

The first image has the correct texture i want to use, but the second image has the realistic metal material i need. Is there a way to transfer either of these two textures, (The suit, or the metal texture) into either of each others rendering engines?
Is there a clear tutorial anyone can link me to or an explanation of how to do this?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13610/convert-materials-from-cycles-to-blender-internal-render , http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles

Comment: Now ... what you want to do is render this robot arm in Cycle engine or Blender internal Engine? Need to be clear about that.

Comment: Look at the top picture, specifically the texture of the suit. Now look at the bottom picture, specifically the metal material texture. I want both of these to be in the same scene. However, I am not even sure if it is possible to retain the blender internal suit texture while in cycles, or vice versa for the metal material.

Answer (score 1):

Use the python script here:

[How do I convert materials from Blender Internal to Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles)

it should help you convert the BI materials to Cycles.
Hope this helps!