# Cycles material to Blender Render Material

Tags: materials

I'm having trouble rendering the materials shown in Cycles render to Blender Render. Is there any way I can convert this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13610/convert-materials-from-cycles-to-blender-internal-render and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles

Answer (score 1):

Try **[Material Utilities Specials](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Materials_Utils)**. It comes bundled with Blender. You may need to enable it in User preferences / Addons.

Also note that the recently bundled versions of the addon may not have the ability to convert materials. In this case, just download the addon from the link above and enable the downloaded version instead of the bundled version.

Then, with your objects selected, press Shift + Q to call the Materials Specials Menu -> Specials -> to BI Nodes Off.

[image]

*Note that you may need to manually add textures you may have used in your material definitions in Cycles.*

Answer (score -1):

Just do clic on the button shown on the image. [image]