# Make hair in Blender Internal, but render in Cycle, realistic skin in blender render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, particles, blender-internal-render-engine

Even though I have made a character and applied material and some lightning effect, I still can't get somewhat skinny color - somewhat red as like real one.

In this [video by Andrew Price](http://youtu.be/jEnCsvcvX8k?t=26m19s), the object is not so real, but when rendered it gives very realistic image!

And I want to make hair for my character. I found every one using Cycles. But when I do Cycles render it takes forever, about half an hour for an image. So I want to make hair in Cycles and later choose Blender Internal. What will happen if I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't change any of the particle settings, then there would be no problem rendering the hair in cycles and blender internal. **Note** you will need two different materials, one for the internal, and one for cycles.
See [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6446/2217) question for how to use materials in blender internal and cycles.

Comment: how can i bring plane or any shape as a source of light in blender render?

Comment: @asheshshrestha You can't really.. BI doesn't support this (You can *kind of* do this with indirect lighting, but I don't recommend it). Best to use cycles or an area lamp (or whatever kind of lamp fits your needs).