# Appended layer not rendering any objects

Tags: rendering, render-layers, append

I'm something of a noob to blender.  I appended a model of an engine to the 2nd layer of my project, and for some reason, no objects from this model show up when I render.  If I add a cube to the 2nd layer, the cube shows up behind an outline of the engine, but not the engine itself.  The object in layer 1 shows up fine.  For the life of me I cannot find why the objects from this model don't show up.  I have the render visibility turned on for all of them, and I can't find anything else that would change visibility (ie the layer is lit, etc.)

Can anyone point out to me what I'm missing? Its probably something obvious.  Here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5q1lnq91oxtpkbg/Blend%20for%20SE.blend?dl=0

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6446/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13610/599, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1756/599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your material is set up for cycles rendering but you have it set to blender render at the top. Then the object in layer 1 is set up for blender internal rendering.

Comment: How do I switch them over to blender internal? Or is there even a reason for me to?

Comment: To switch the material to blender internal you can delete the material and then create a new one but you will have to start from scratch. If you create a material while cycles is active that material will work with cycles, if you create a material while internal is active it will be for internal. You have to decide if you want to use cycles or blender internal and then create all your materials consistently in one or the other based on your choice.