# Make Cycles materials transparent but present in BI

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, scene

I am using a multi-scene setup to render out some passes in Blender Internal for anti-aliasing purposes. I have a primary scene with Cycles materials, and a secondary Blender Internal scene. The Cycles materials do not work in BI of course, and instead come up transparent.

However, some materials behave differently than others. I have Solid and Edge enabled in the BI render layer, as my goal is to get Normal pass and edge lines. For some materials, it renders out the Edge and has the normal pass, while otherwise only having alpha. For others, it is only alpha and the objects are missing entirely. I want only the first behavior.

When I have the second behavior, if I remove the material, then I get the Edge and Normal Pass, but also the regular Solid render instead of transparency. Using a material override of a material with the first behavior does not help.

In the material preview, materials with the first behavior show a sphere. For the second, it shows only their shadow.

What causes this different behavior?

Comment: I think you need to upload some test blend with example, with the setup. I am not sure if I got it right. Also you don't probably have to use BI at all and make your render layers in Cycles with materials - like a normal colors material etc.

Comment: I'll see if I can get a file. The problem is this issue is really inconsistent, and I don't want to put out my current project. Will try to reproduce it in a fresh file.

Comment: Some related questions: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6446/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/562/599